create variable with multiple values in azure pipeline yaml
I can only assign a single value to a variable in azure pipeline YAML file, this is how I have now on Azure.
parameters:
- name: env
  displayName: 'Environment'
  type: string
  default: ''
  
variables:
  - name: sys_file1
    value: 'first_file.xml'
  - name: sys_file2
    value: 'second_file.xml'

In Azure pipeline bash scripts, I need to read filename from variables and make an update on each of them. I have already done the changes for one filename using variable sys_file1. Now, we could have multiple files which needs the same update.
How can I read all filename and make same change on each of them?
Option 1: Can I defined multiple values to single variable, and then iterate over list of values in bash script?
Option 2: In bash script, how can I read filenames through variables with are matching regex sys_file*?


Can I defined multiple values to single variable, and then iterate over list of values in bash script?

Yes. This can be achieved.
Here is an example:
variables:
  - name: sys_file
    value: 'first_file.xml second_file.xml third_file.xml'

steps:
- bash: |
    for item in $(sys_file); do
      echo "$item"  
    done

Result:

On the other hand, you can also consider using the Pipeline Built-in feature: Each expression to loop the variable values.
Here is an example:
variables:
- name:  sys_file
  value: first_file.xml,second_file.xml,third_file.xml
 
steps:
- ${{ each file in split(variables.sys_file,',') }}:
  - bash: |
      echo  ${{ file  }}

In this case, the pipeline will add corresponding bash tasks to run the script according to the number of variable values.
Result:


Since you split by blank, and glob expand the shell variable in a for loop. How do you handle file names with spaces, tabs and newline in them? How do you prevent values containing a star a question mark or charcter class names from being globbed to matching file names?

@LéaGris If the string contains spaces, tabs or other characters,(exclude quotes) you can use the following format to define the value: value: '"first_ * file.xml" "second_file *  .xml" "third *  _file.xml"' . Use double quotes to format each file name.
